# +layout.js or +layout.svelte for mixpanel integration in SvelteKit project when +layout.server.js already exists

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, mixpanel

I want to integrate [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) to my [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) project by following official documentation at https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/javascript-quickstart

To integrate I have initilise mixpanel using code

```js
import mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';

mixpanel.init('YOUR_TOKEN', {debug: true}); 
mixpanel.track('test event');
```

Where should I add this mixpanel initialisation so I can track events on my desired pages?

My project already have `+layout.server.js` and I can not initilise mixpanel in this file becase this will run on server side.

Now I have choice of `+layout.js` and `+layout.svelte`.
If I choose to use `+layout.js` then it will conflict with `+layout.server.js`
If I choose to use `+layout.svelte` then I am not sure if I can expose mixpanel globally to child pages.

So what should be right way to integrate mixpanel if `+layout.server.js` is present in project?

Answer (score 1):

In `+layout.js` put

```
import { PUBLIC_MIXPANEL_TOKEN } from "$env/static/public";
import mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';

mixpanel.init(PUBLIC_MIXPANEL_TOKEN, { debug: true });
```

In the page which you want to track e.g. `+page.svelte`

```
import mixpanel from "mixpanel-browser";

onMount(() => {
    mixpanel.track("HomePage", { name: 'Alok' });
});
```

If we dont want to import `mixpanel` in `+page.svelte` then we can pass mixpnel variable via `load` function in `+layout.js`